# Can someone please explain the following code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

Can someone please explain the following the below code, especially the `new[]`

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.WillAttend,new[] { 
          new SelectListItem() { Text = "Yes, I'll be there", Value = bool.TrueString},
          new SelectListItem() { Text = "No, I can't come", Value = bool.FalseString}}, "Choose an option")
```

Does the `new[]` creates a new select list?

Comment: [Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)

Comment: @Sayse `new[]` is not an anonymous type. It's an implicitly typed array.

Comment: @HenkMollema - I misread the documentation, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new[]` is *not* an anonymous type, it's an [implicitly typed array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx) of type `SelectListItem[]`. The type of the array (`SelectListItem`) is inferred when you add items of type `SelectListItem` using the [array initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

You are using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703462%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) of `DropDownListFor`. Since `SelectListItem[]` derives from `IEnumerable<SelectListItem`, this works. You also could have used a `List` for example: `new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { ... },  new SelectListItem { ... } }`.

Answer (score 0):

The code creates a new array of the type `SelectList` and adds two new `SelectListItem` items to it. That is your new dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the new[] creates a new select list?

`new[]` creates a new Array object. Considering that second parameter of `DropDownListFor`
is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, array smoothly casts to required type.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, the new[] in an array, list initializer. So in this case, you create an array or a list, I don't know the type which a dropdownlistfor accepts and it has 2 items of type SelectListItem.

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.DropDownListFor()` looks like a Razor statement for the Razor view engine. This statement will generate a HTML select list. The argmuent of this function (the stuff between the `()`) makes up the contents of the list which in this case is generated from the statement `new[]{...}` that creates a new array populated with the items within the `{}` in this case `SelectListItem`s.

The statement as a whole should generate something that looks like:

```
<select>
      <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Choose an option</option>
      <option value="true">Yes, I'll be there</option>
      <option value="false">No, I can't come</option>
</select>
```